# mysql get first and last entry with same value in other column

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table with a date column and a price column.
The date column has a row for each day of the year.

The table is like this:

```
2017-09-01 158.00
2017-09-02 158.00
2017-09-03 158.00
2017-09-04 158.00
etc.
2017-09-10 175.00
2017-09-11 175.00
etc.
2017-10-20 158.00
2017-10-21 158.00
```

I want to get the first date and last date in a time range that has same price.

So the result for above should be:

```
    2017-09-01 -- 2017-09-04 158 euro.
    2017-09-10 -- 2017-09-11 175 euro.
    2017-10-20 -- 2017-10-21 158 euro.
```

Comment: This is a tough one because you want a new pair of dates the next time the price returns to 158; so in the OP you have three results even though there are only 2 prices.  What do you think about parsing the results in PHP?

Comment: Actually I have much more with same price, even with different years.
Its only for printing out the prices for the different periods, may be repeated in same year and may not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you. It's based on another answer I gave here. You loop through the days, accumulating every day that has the same price as before in an array. Every time the loop detects a change in the price, a new array is created, and so on.

```
<?php
$values[] = ["2017-09-01", "158.00"];
$values[] = ["2017-09-02", "158.00"];
$values[] = ["2017-09-03", "158.00"];
$values[] = ["2017-09-04", "158.00"];
$values[] = ["2017-09-10", "175.00"];
$values[] = ["2017-09-11", "175.00"];
$values[] = ["2017-10-20", "158.00"];
$values[] = ["2017-10-21", "158.00"];
$values[] = ["2017-10-22", "159.00"];
$values[] = ["2017-10-23", "152.00"];
$values[] = ["2017-10-24", "152.00"];
$ult = null;
$currentRange = [];
$ranges = [];
foreach ($values as $fecha) {
    $day = $fecha[0];
    $price = $fecha[1];
    if ($ult === null) {
        $currentRange = [
            "price" => $price, 
            "days" => [$day]
        ];
    }
    else {
        if ($price === $ult) {
            $currentRange["days"][] = $day;
        }
        else {
            $ranges[] = $currentRange;
            $currentRange = [
                "price" => $price, 
                "days" => [$day]
            ];
        }
    }
    $ult = $price;
}
$ranges[] = $currentRange;
$rangesString = [];
foreach ($ranges as $range) {
    $str = $range["days"][0];
    if (count($range["days"]) > 1) {
        $str .= " - ".$range["days"][count($range["days"]) - 1];
    }
    $str .= ": ".$range["price"];
    $rangesString[] = $str;
}
echo (implode("<br>", $rangesString));

/* results:
2017-09-01 - 2017-09-04: 158.00
2017-09-10 - 2017-09-11: 175.00
2017-10-20 - 2017-10-21: 158.00
2017-10-22: 159.00
2017-10-23 - 2017-10-24: 152.00
*/
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/1soaC)

Comment: That looks fantastic, exactly what I want. A million of thanks

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Sorry...As in the example I suppose I need to output the PDO query as an array same as in your example. When I add my query it don´t work, so suppose I am not outputting the query correctly as an array

Comment: I managed to get it work, outputting the query like this: while 
($values = $gsent->fetchall()) {
and changing this in your script: 
$day = $fecha[0];
$price = $fecha[1];
to:
$day = $fecha['cal_date'];
$price = $fecha['price_client'];

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If your date column is Dte and amount column is amt then your query should be like this

```sql
SELECT MIN(Dte), MAX(Dte), CONCAT(amt,' euro') FROM test 
GROUP BY amt
```

Comment: Thanks, but that groups all with same price together...I only want the days that are consecutive. In my example above 1-4 sept and 20-21 oct has same price but I want October separately from September as are not consecutive days...